# Building/Running/Tasks multiple dotnet project in Visual Studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a project structure like the following and I would like to be able to run tasks on all projects at once so that i maybe able to build and run as well as run tests on all projects in one command using Visual Studio code? is this possible?

```
-global.json
-src
    -Web
        -project.json
        -program.cs
    -Web2
        -project.json
        -program.cs
-test
    -Web.Test
        -project.json
        -program.cs
    -Web2.Test
        -project.json
        -program.cs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a solution file to your root folder with `dotnet new sln`. You can then add project references with `dotnet sln add` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln

`dotnet build` will then build all referenced projects, and `dotnet test` will run all unit tests found.